# How to solve The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY EB3E94ADBE1229CF

Tags: linux, ubuntu, sql

I am trying to install SQL server on Linux using Ubuntu from this link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/quickstart-install-connect-ubuntu?view=sql-server-ver16&tabs=ubuntu2204

And, in executing step 3 I am getting below error messages:

```
sudo apt-get update
Hit:1 https://cli.github.com/packages stable InRelease
Get:2 https://packages.microsoft.com/ubuntu/22.04/prod jammy InRelease [3631 B]
Get:3 https://packages.microsoft.com/ubuntu/22.04/mssql-server-2022 jammy InRelease [3603 B]
Err:2 https://packages.microsoft.com/ubuntu/22.04/prod jammy InRelease
  The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY EB3E94ADBE1229CF
Hit:4 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security InRelease
Err:3 https://packages.microsoft.com/ubuntu/22.04/mssql-server-2022 jammy InRelease
  The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY EB3E94ADBE1229CF
Reading package lists... Done
W: GPG error: https://packages.microsoft.com/ubuntu/22.04/prod jammy InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY EB3E94ADBE1229CF
```

Comment: Try `sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys EB3E94ADBE1229CF` and then `sudo apt update`.

Comment: apt-key is depreciating and 22.04 is the last version that supports it. The proper way is use [wget](https://www.linuxuprising.com/2021/01/apt-key-is-deprecated-how-to-add.html?utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=feed&utm_campaign=Feed:+LinuxUprising+(Linux+Uprising)&m=1) or curl. My suggestion is **update** your Ubuntu installation.

Comment: @harrymc I have tried your mentioned command, here is console output:sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys EB3E94ADBE1229CF
Warning: apt-key is deprecated. Manage keyring files in trusted.gpg.d instead (see apt-key(8)).
Executing: /tmp/apt-key-gpghome.KlEbj3Y5YG/gpg.1.sh --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys EB3E94ADBE1229CF
gpg: keyserver receive failed: Server indicated a failure

Comment: @Ramhound I have 22.04 version Welcome to Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS (GNU/Linux 5.15.133.1-microsoft-standard-WSL2 x86_64)

Comment: You should add new information to your post - comments are hard to read. Try the answers in this post: [How to add the APT key for Microsoft packages](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1245227/how-to-add-the-apt-key-for-microsoft-packages).

Answer (score 1):

Running the following command should resolve the error. You can also

> curl -fsSL https://packages.microsoft.com/keys/microsoft.asc | sudo gpg --dearmor -o /usr/share/keyrings/microsoft-prod.gpg

Source: [Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1328834/debian-12-public-key-is-not-available)

Comment: I have tried this command but getting same error occurred

Comment: I need more information. Sounds like you downloaded the gpg certificate but are not pointing to the keyring you put it in when you then ran the depreciated command apt-key.   Manage trusted.gpg.d as the previous command suggested